# Find new, removed and same elements in a vector or collection compared to another

Tags: c++, collections

Considering you have two collections containing no duplicates:

```
std::vector<T*> previous;
std::vector<T*> current;
```

Is there an elegant way to split these two collections into three collections containing the elements that are the same in both, the elements in **current** that were not in **previous** and the elements that were in **previous** that are not in **current**? Resulting in:

```
std::vector<T*> removed;
std::vector<T*> same;
std::vector<T*> inserted;
```

Is there maybe a std:: function that does that?

EDIT:

The collections can be sorted but as they are collections of pointers by what metric but their address value?

The collections should not contain duplicates.

Comment: Are the vectors sorted?

Comment: You can sort them beforehand if that makes it easier. (It propably will ... ) Though as you are dealing with pointers the only metric to sort for is address value ...

Comment: Does "elegant" include or exclude "efficient"? If efficiency is not too much of an issue, `std::set` arithmetic would be elegant. Oh, and what about duplicate entries?

Comment: I'd consider elegant anything that is either efficient OR pretty to look at. Be it inefficient but only 3 lines of code long or efficient but needing some advanced math skills ... I do not want to exclude any solution that gets the actual work done but is not simply brute forcing everything in 4 for loops or something. There should be no duplicates.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164426/set-difference-and-set-intersection-simultaneously)?

Comment: I am not sure ... the < is a bit confusing as I am only interested in equality but I guess if I look harder at the accepted answer I will get why a < compare is enough ...

Answer (score 0):

You can first find intersection (*same* vector) of current and previous using [std::set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/). After that, it’s possible to find removed and inserted using [std::set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) by subtracting found intersection from previous and current correspondingly.

Comment: Reading the words intersection and difference I now realize how the temporal aspect of my problem completly blinded me to what words I should use for what I am actually looking for ... and reading them makes the solution quite obvious ...

Comment: I think what he wants is the opposite of intersection. It's like `union - intersection`

Comment: No ... interstection = both; a - both = only_a ; b - both = only_b ; seems correct to me